# Changing bricks sprite position everytime I restsrt the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a brick breaker game in which Bricks are placed as follows:

[image: bricks]

Now what I want is that whenever I start my new game or restart after game over the bricks should get changed randomly but the position should not change!

Does anyone know how I can do this? Should I change the Bricks script or the Inspector itself or both?

This is the bricks script:

```
public class BricksScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "ball") {
            gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you position a brick randomly on the screen?  Can you seed the random number generator from the system clock?  Those two should get you a long way to solving your problem.

Comment: yes I can do that using random function But I don't want to position it randomly anywhere !

Comment: @dutaravi12345 You have a list of positions and a list of colors. The second one gets randomized. Then you assign colors in the second list to positions in the first list. Simple as that. If you want the amount of each color being static, you initialize the color list with the correct amounts and then use a permutation/shuffle on it (search for that).

Comment: OK I will try @Aziuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u all I solved my problem as follows:

- first I created an `empty gameobject` and attach a `script` to it.
- then I coded the script as follows:

  ```
  public class positionsBricks : MonoBehaviour {

      public GameObject[] bricks;
      int brickNo;
      // Use this for initialization
      void Start () {
          Vector3 Brickpos = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
          brickNo = Random.Range (0, bricks.Length);
          Instantiate (bricks [brickNo], Brickpos, transform.rotation);
      }

      // Update is called once per frame
      void Update () {

      }
  }
  ```

**At inspector I drag and dropped all prefabs**  in script and then

- I duplicated the `gameobject` and placed it at the same positions where the earlier original `prefabs` were and deleted the old one

Answer (score 0):

My Unity is installed elsewhere but here is an overall idea:

- Create an empty gameobject and attach a script that manages the bricks.
- In the hierarchy, attach the bricks to the brickmanager object.
- In the brick manager scripts `Start()` method:

  - loop through the bricks once to get all their positions and store them in a list
  - and a second time to assign them random positions from your list.

Alternatively you can hardcode the positions as code in your brick manager script or use empty gameobjects to hold the positions.

Comment: what about if I create an empty gameobject and attach a script to it which will have an array of gameobjects and then attach all gameobj(bricks) in inspector only by making array public then use `Random.range` and `Instantiate` in the start function ...about position I use `Vector3` to get their curent position without changing them ? @Robin Koch

Comment: What do u think ?

Comment: can u explain the loop idea through some code...better if give some overall code example .Bcoz I m newbie

Comment: Sorry, I can't go into to much detail, because it's some time ago since I worked on Unity. But I remember using a strategy similar to the described for placing game objects. (We had to place objects in a random subset of n positions.) - I took a look at your screenshot: might it be a solution to keeps the positions, but to pick color (or prefab) randomly for each brick? This way you won't need a manager script.

Comment: yes I want to pick color(prefab) randomly each time I start or restart the game !